# How to create a list of Tcl commands in a text file and then run it in ISim?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, xilinx-ise

Seems a lot more convenient than typing each one individually every time.

This link was very unclear to me:

http://sagekingthegreat.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-execute-tcl-script-in-xilinx.html

Sample Code:

```
#Sample Script:

restart
run 20 ns 
dump
run 20 ns
dump
quit
```

I'm just looking for the Tcl command to enter in the Console Window of the Simulation GUI to run these commands (entered in Notepad ++, and saved as a .tcl file in my project folder)

Comment: Please include what you have tried doing so far. Your current question might be considered too broad by some people. Also, a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), might help improve your question.

Comment: *edited.    But there's really not too much to it.  The internet and other Xilinx documentation inlcuding this link (http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx12_1/ism_r_simulation_command_overview.htm) were not much help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass your tcl file as a parametet to your compiled/fused testbench via `-tclbatch <filename>`.

```
.\fifo_tb.exe -tclbatch fifo_tb.tcl -gui
```

`-gui` opens the testbench in GUI mode with iSim connected to the testbench executable.

To see all supported options of a testbench, run the testbench executable  with `-h`.

To show all supported TCL commands in iSim, use the `help` command. I'm currently not aware of any loadfile/source/do instruction for iSim.

**Example fifo_cc_got_tb:**

1. All needed VHDL files are listed in a fifo_cc_got_tb.prj file:

   ```
   vhdl poc "D:\git\PoC\tb\common\my_config_ML505.vhdl"
   vhdl poc "D:\git\PoC\tb\common\my_project.vhdl"
   vhdl unisim "C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\ISE\vhdl\src\unisims\primitive\MUXCY.vhd"
   vhdl unisim "C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\ISE\vhdl\src\unisims\primitive\XORCY.vhd"
   vhdl poc "D:\git\PoC\src\common\utils.vhdl"
   vhdl poc "D:\git\PoC\src\common\strings.vhdl"
   vhdl poc "D:\git\PoC\src\common\vectors.vhdl"
   vhdl poc "D:\git\PoC\src\common\board.vhdl"
   vhdl poc "D:\git\PoC\src\common\config.vhdl"
   vhdl poc "D:\git\PoC\src\common\physical.vhdl"
   vhdl poc "D:\git\PoC\tb\common\simulation.v93.vhdl"
   vhdl poc "D:\git\PoC\tb\common\simulation.v93.vhdl"
   vhdl poc "D:\git\PoC\src\mem\ocram\ocram.pkg.vhdl"
   vhdl poc "D:\git\PoC\src\mem\ocram\ocram_sdp.vhdl"
   vhdl poc "D:\git\PoC\src\fifo\fifo_cc_got.vhdl"
   vhdl test "D:\git\PoC\tb\fifo\fifo_cc_got_tb.vhdl"
   ```

   The ISE ProjectNavigator collects this information for you and saves it in a prj file.
2. fuse.exe is executed to compile the testbench from given prj file:

   ```
   cd D:\git\PoC\temp\isim\
   C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\ISE\bin\nt64\fuse.exe test.fifo_cc_got_tb --prj fifo_cc_got_tb.prj -o fifo_cc_got_tb.exe
   ```

   This can also be found in the ProjectNavigator console window:

   ```
   Started : "Simulate Behavioral Model".

   Determining files marked for global include in the design...
   Running fuse...
   Command Line: fuse -intstyle ise -incremental -lib secureip -o D:/git/GitHub/PicoBlaze-Examples/Projects/SoFPGA_Atlys_ISE/ise/sync_Strobe_isim_beh.exe -prj D:/git/GitHub/PicoBlaze-Examples/Projects/SoFPGA_Atlys_ISE/ise/sync_Strobe_beh.prj PoC.sync_Strobe {}
   Running: C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\ISE\bin\nt64\unwrapped\fuse.exe -intstyle ise -incremental -lib secureip -o D:/git/GitHub/PicoBlaze-Examples/Projects/SoFPGA_Atlys_ISE/ise/sync_Strobe_isim_beh.exe -prj D:/git/GitHub/PicoBlaze-Examples/Projects/SoFPGA_Atlys_ISE/ise/sync_Strobe_beh.prj PoC.sync_Strobe
   ```
3. The simulation is launched with a TCL script

   ```
   .\fifo_cc_got_tb.exe -tclbatch ..\..\sim\iSim.gui.tcl -gui
   ```

   Also this can be seen in the ProjectNavigators console window:

   ```
   ....
   Compiled 21 VHDL Units
   Built simulation executable D:/git/GitHub/PicoBlaze-Examples/Projects/SoFPGA_Atlys_ISE/ise/sync_Strobe_isim_beh.exe
   Fuse Memory Usage: 50240 KB
   Fuse CPU Usage: 529 ms
   Launching ISim simulation engine GUI...
   "D:/git/GitHub/PicoBlaze-Examples/Projects/SoFPGA_Atlys_ISE/ise/sync_Strobe_isim_beh.exe" -intstyle ise -gui -tclbatch isim.cmd  -wdb "D:/git/GitHub/PicoBlaze-Examples/Projects/SoFPGA_Atlys_ISE/ise/sync_Strobe_isim_beh.wdb"
   ISim simulation engine GUI launched successfully
   ```

Here is the Simulation Process Property dialog to setup a user defined TCL script (red option) and if needed a user defined waveform configuration file (*.wcfg) green option.

[image]

Comment: This sounds right, but is there anyway you could break this down further for a beginner?  Like what fuse is/does and what <filename> specifically?

Comment: The simulation compiler for ISE simulator (iSim) is called fuse.exe. It compiles all given vhdl and verilog files to an executable (e.g. fifo_tb.exe if you testbench's name is fifo_tb). The list of files which should be compiled is saved in a prj file (e.g. fifo_tb.prj). When you launch your simulation, the executable and iSim.exe (the simulator GUI) are started. Both processes communicate via TCP sessions. Filename is you tcl script.

Comment: You're awesome, thank you!  Just to be clear though, if my testbench is "adder_tb.vhd" and my tcl file is "testrun.tcl".  I would enter _.\adder_tb.exe -tclbatch testrun.tcl -g_  into the [Command Window shown here](https://i.imgur.com/pOHrKew.jpg) to run my .tcl command file?

Comment: No, console means Windows console either cmd.exe or powershell. Alternativly, you can configure an user defined tcl script in iSim process properties in the ISE project navigator.

Comment: ...lost again..  So how do you know to use either cmd.exe or powershell?  How do I get to these in Windows7?

Comment: ?? Have you never used the windows command prompt a.k.a console or cmd.exe? Powershell (PS or PoSh) is the successor of cmd. I prefer powershell because of it's power and featues.

Comment: ahh okay so you enter " .\fifo_tb.exe -tclbatch fifo_tb.tcl -g" into the command prompt and it will pull up Xilinx and Isim (specifically the 2 files  above)

Comment: Exacly :) If you start iSim from ISE navigator, you'll see the executed commands in the log window. The first command is fuse.exe to compile all files (something like fuse.exe -prj fifo_tb.prj -mt 2 ....) the second should call fifo_tb.exe.

Comment: I'm getting this error (http://i.imgur.com/TjlXXhr.jpg ) every time I try and run my testbench and tcl file in the command prompt.  Any ideas!?!

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. Option `-g` is `-gui`. I extended my answer with an fifo_cc_got exampe and snippets from the project navigator log. I also added a screenshot from the simulation process property dialog, where you can setup these command line options for the usage in ISE.